# How to hide the button?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site

I'm using SharePoint Online modern UI.

And, I want to hide `Quick edit, Sync, Export to Excel, PowerApps, Automate` from my site.

Please check below picture.

Could you tell me how to hide that menu?

[image: this is my question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use spfx to upload custom css file to sharepoint online to hide  special button.

Example on how to upload css file in spfx:

https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss

Comment: I found about PowerApps and Automate Button below Link. <br> But I can't find other buttons. <br>  https://mbangert.de/hide-power-apps-and-power-automate-flow-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: Sorry I post another new Qustion for update.